# Postgresql inserts stop at random number of records

Tags: database, postgresql, insert, limit, record

I am developing a test application that requires me to insert 1 million records in a Postgresql database but at random points the insert stops and if I try to restart the insertion process, the application refuses to populate the table with more records. I've read that databases have a size cap, which is around 4 Gb, but I'm sure my database didn't even come close to this value.

So, what other reasons could be for why insertion stopped?

It happened a few times, once capping at 170872 records, another time at 25730 records.

I know the question might sound silly but I can't find any other reasons for why it stops inserting.

Thanks in advance!

**JUST A QUICK UPDATE:**

Indeed the problem isn't the database cap, here are the official figures for PostgreSQL:

```
- Maximum Database Size                 Unlimited
- Maximum Table Size                    32 TB
- Maximum Row Size                      1.6 TB
- Maximum Field Size                    1 GB
- Maximum Rows per Table                Unlimited
- Maximum Columns per Table             250 - 1600 depending on column types
- Maximum Indexes per Table             Unlimited
```

**Update:**

Error in log file:

**2012-03-26 12:30:12 EEST WARNING: there is no transaction in progress**

So I'm looking up for an answer that fits this issue. If you can give any hints I would be very grateful.

Comment: Does your database have a timeout for single calls?  If your call takes more time than that without a commit it will stop the call(this is in place to prevent full database hangs). Did it give you some other error that would be helpful to us?

Comment: I don't know what timeout for single call is, but I think I understand what you mean. I will modify my code and rerun it. It might take a while until I come back with an answer.

Comment: Make sure to come back with an error message as well if it still doesnt work.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker Good one :)

Comment: I have a database with ~15 35 GB tables not counting indexes. One of them grows by about a million records a day. I was told on the DBA site this is peanuts. To echo @RichardHuxton, this is almost certainly an application problem and not a PostgreSQL problem.

Comment: @reos: Please update your question with: Version of the server, client language and version of client connector library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>I found out what was the problem with my insert command, and although it might seem funny it's one of those things you never thought could go wrong.</s>

My application is developed in Django and has a command that simply calls for the file that does the insert operations into the tables.

i.e. in the command line terminal I just write:

```
time python manage.py populate_sql
```

The reason for which I use the `time` command is because I want to see how long it takes for the insertion to execute. Well, the problem was here. That  `time` command issued an error, a **`Out of memory`** error which stopped the insertion into the database. I found this little code while running the command with the **--verbose** option which lets you see all the details of the command.

I would like to thank you all for your answers, for the things that I have learned from them and for the time you used trying to help me.

**EDIT:**

If you have a Django application in which you make a lot of operations with the database, then my advice to you is to set the **'DEBUG'** variable in settings.py to **'FALSE'** because it eats up a lot of your memory in time.

So,

```
DEBUG = False
```

And in the end, thank you again for the support Richard Huxton!

Comment: It almost certainly wasn't "time" that was generating an "out of memory" error, but your script.

Comment: The error was 'time %.3f' Memory error or something like this.

Comment: It wasn't "something like this" - it was a specific error from a specific source. Try and get in the habit of cutting + pasting error messages into a text-file. Attention to detail is vital when trouble-shooting. If you'd checked your application for errors at the beginning you could have saved yourself hours of work.

Comment: I tried to save the output of the command in a .txt file but when the error occured there the execution stopped and when I checked the .txt there was nothing written in the file. And because the insert operation lasted for about 5 hours until it threw the error, I couldn't try it all the time. I will, however print the exact error tomorrow when I will have enough time to try it again.

Comment: There's not much need now, surely. Your application is running out of memory, presumably because you're not discarding any of the 1 million rows you're trying to insert. BTW - is there any reason you're not using PostgreSQL's COPY functionality for a bulk import?

Comment: Please give a little more details, this is my first time using PostgreSQL. And regarding the discarding part, I am commiting at every 100 inserts, shouldn't that be sufficient?

Comment: I can't tell you why your application is using lots of memory, I haven't seen it. If all you are doing is inserting, it's impossible that the PostgreSQL server has anything to do with it and very unlikely that it's the database driver. Run your app, monitor its memory usage - does it increase constantly? If so, find out where you are not releasing unneeded objects and do so.

Comment: Indeed you were right, my application was using too much memory, but not because I didn't delete my unused objects, but because Django has a peculiar option in the settings.py file, 'DEBUG' variable, that when making a lot of operations with the database, if not set to 'FALSE', then it will eat up your memory like crazy. I will edit my answer and thank you for your help @RichardHuxton!

Answer (score 4):

> I've read that databases have a size cap, which is around 4 Gb

I rather doubt that. It's certainly not true about PostgreSQL.

> [...]at random points the insert stops and if I try to restart the insertion process, the application refuses to populate the table with more records

Again, I'm afraid I doubt this. Unless your application has become self aware it's refusing to do nothing. It might be crashing, or locking, or waiting for something to happen though.

> I know the question might sound silly but I can't find any other reasons for why it stops inserting.

I don't think you've looked hard enough. Obvious things to check:

1. Are you getting any errors in the PostgreSQL logs?
2. If not, are you sure you're logging errors? Issue a bad query to check.
3. Are you getting any errors in the application?
4. If not,. are you sure you're checking? Again, check
5. What is/are the computer(s) up to? How much CPU/RAM/Disk IO is in use? Any unusual activity?
6. Any unusual locks begin taken (check the `pg_locks` view).

If you asked the question having checked the above then there's someone who'll be able to help. Probably though, you'll figure it out yourself once you've got the facts in front of you.

Comment: About the size cap, I've done some more research and I found out it's 32TB fot tables, 1.6TB for rows and unlimited for the database.

Comment: Thank you for your hints, I'm going to check all of them.

Comment: 3. No errors inside the application 4. I've checked and rechecked. 5. The CPU/RAM usage is inside a normal range, no unusual activity so far as I have restarted the modified code and only about 65.000 records have been inserted into the tables.

Comment: If you aren't getting any errors then presumably the application is stalling at some point. Find where (logging/debugger) and also check for database locks while it's stalled.

Comment: I'll probably come back in about a few hours to see if my application has finished successfully finished and if not I will rerun it with logging and debugging on.

Comment: If you did not have the logging "and debuggin" ? on before, how could you know that is was stalled at **exactly** 170872 or 25730 records? Who did the counting?

Comment: I did the counting, I accessed the tables in the database and just did a simple SELECT COUNT(*) from mytable;

Comment: Funny thing is that it stopped again at 171050 records.

Comment: After looking at the log I can see there's an error: There's no transaction in progress.

Answer (score 1):

OK - if you're getting "no transaction in progress" that means you're issuing a commit/rollback but outside of an explicit transaction. If you don't issue a "BEGIN" then each statement gets its own transaction.

This is unlikely to be the cause of the problem.

Something is causing the inserts to stop, and you've still not told us what. You said earlier you weren't getting any errors inside the application. That shouldn't be possible if PostgreSQL is returning an error you should be picking it up in the application.

It's difficult to be more helpful without more accurate information. Every statement you send to PostgreSQL will return a status code. If you get an error inside a multi-statement transaction then all the statements in that transaction will be rolled back. You've either got some confused transaction control in the application or it is falling down for some other reason.

Comment: I've looked more thorough and although my application didn't give out any errors I managed to find an IntegrityError inside a log and fixed it. I've restarted the application and the inserting part and I'll come back with an answer in a few hours telling you if it passed the 170k mark or not.

Comment: If you are getting errors in the database but not in the application, you probably need to fix the application before worrying about anything else. Always check the return code of external commands.

Answer (score 0):

One of the possibilities is that the OP is using ssl, and the ssl_renegotiation_limit is reached. In any case: set the log_connections / log_disconnections to "On" and check the logfile.

Comment: Could you please clarify what OP means?

Comment: "Original Poster" (or "original Post") In this case: reos.